# jQuery .click function doesn't work with middle button

Tags: jquery, function, click

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#TestLink").click(function() {
                    $("#LinkHolder").html("test");
    });
});

<span id="LinkHolder">
<a href="SomeLink" id="TestLink" target="_blank">Click here to test</a>
</span>
```

Everything works like a charm when I click with left mouse button on the link, but when I click it with CTRL+LeftMouseButton or MiddleMouseButton it doesn't work.

Will be glad if someone can help me with this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, you should explain why you would want to click a link with the middle button.

Comment: because some users open the links not only with left mouse button?

Comment: isn't it almost a standard now that middle-clicking a link opens it in a new tab?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#TestLink").mouseup(function(e) {
                    $("#LinkHolder").html("test");
    });
});
```

As an alternative? This does detect middle mouse button clicks.

Comment: And according to this, you can find out which button was clicked by looking at e.button: From http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: Forgot to mention that this disables the default behaviour of link clicks, for that add in: window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'), '_blank);

Comment: btw. instead of: window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'), '_blank); I use $(e).attr("href"); because the action is on the <a link, so with your way it returns "undefined". If the action was on the span, than yours will work too. anyway, your suggestion saves me a lot of time. thanks again

Comment: You need to handle both `click` and `mouseup`; otherwise you don't get an event if you tab to the link and press the ENTER key.

Comment: Won't this also have the affect of detecting right-clicks? Which you presumably wouldn't want.